# External Hard Drive Size Problem

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, external-disk, disk-format

I recently bought a 4 TB Seagate Desktop Expansion external hard drive. However, after formatting it with Disk Utility the device still says 4 TB but the capacity says 1.8 TB. What is going on?

Comment: Can you run the command `diskutil list`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you completely wiped it via the Apple Disk utilities and formatted it Mac Journaled? It might look like you kept a partition of the disk (FAT32 or NTFS)